# Azure functions - getting configuration recommended practices

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have created an Azure Function v2. In most articles I people suggest following:

```
 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
```

Does a function hosted on azure also have a local.settings.json file? Will this code snippet get the app settings defined in Azure? Or do you need to change local.settings.json before publish? I thought local.settings.json was a local developer thing?

Is there any recommended practices using above snippet vs

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("xx")?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way you posted works just fine, both locally and in the cloud.

Note: In Azure, there is no local.settings.json (or should never be). This is only being used when debugging locally. There it is being picked up by the Functions runtime the same way it picks up AppSettings when running in Azure - and the settings are injected into your app as env variables. I have been using this for most of the time.

However, I recently started to switch to the second way, using Environment variables (`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("xx")`). Why? Simply because it is shorter and requires not extra usings etc. Apart from that there is no difference that I am aware of in using either of those ways.

Comment: Kind of funny local.settings will be picked up in the cloud too :D I will follow your strategy. It looks much cleaner to me, and if result is same thats the road to go. Thanks for your reply, highly appreciated.

Comment: Well it certainly would get picked up with the first approach. Or did you mean as well with the second way? I never tested this (as it's simply not meant to be used ;) )